# Issue updating Realm on same property

Tags: realm, realm-list

i have a list something like

```
 List<ChatMessage> l = realm.where(ChatMessage.class).equalTo("msg_receive_status", "0").findAll();
```

now what i want is to make "msg_recieve_status" = 1

so i tried with,

```
    int count = l.size();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ChatMessage m = l.get(i);
        m.setMsg_receive_status("1");
    }
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(l);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

but it doesn't work at all.

> I think `msg_receive_status` is updating RealmList real time. and that's cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into problems because the query result is "live", i.e. it is always up to date. We are in the process of merging a fix for the next release here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2124

A work-around is described here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/640#issuecomment-103798064

Which in your case translates to:

```
List<ChatMessage> l = realm.where(ChatMessage.class).equalTo("msg_receive_status", "0").findAll();

realm.beginTransaction();
for (int i = l.size() -1; i >=0; i--) {
   l.get(i).setMsg_receive_status("1");
}
realm.commitTransaction();
```